# Setting IPs for multiple NICs on same server

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I would like to check my understanding on assigning IPs in the same subnet to multiple NICs in the same server.

I have a server with 2 NICs (say, NIC1 and NIC2). My goal was to, after setting IP1 to NIC1, and IP2 to NIC2, have packets destined for IP1 to go to NIC1, and packets destined for IP2 to go to NIC2. Both IP1 and IP2 are in the same subnet. I've read that this is a bad idea, and indeed, I'm facing connectivity issues.

For example, all traffic seems to go to NIC1. When I did a tcpdump on NIC1, it's receiving packets with dest.ip = IP1 and IP2. However, NIC2 seems to not be able to receive any packets.

I think I have mistakenly thought that setting the IPs on the respective interfaces meant that the interface would only receive traffic from the assigned IP.

However, I've tried to set an IP from another subnet on NIC2, and it cannot ping another IP belonging to the same (new) subnet either.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my NIC2 - it shouldn't be a hardware issue as I have other servers with the same problem, i.e. 2 NICs, but only NIC1 is able to send/receive traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Linux systems will, by default, answer ARP requests for IPv4 addresses belonging to *any* interface, not only the interface that the request was received on.

If you have two interfaces in the same subnet, the sending host will receive ARP replies for the same IP address from both interfaces and will learn the wrong MAC address half the time.

Set the `arp_ignore` sysctl to avoid this:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/90-net.conf
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
```